# Are moderators able to remove the monthly question quota for a particular user?

Tags: support, moderators, monthly-question-limit

I have seen several discussions where a user was asking about possibility of removing 50 questions per 30 days quota. If moderators do not have a right to do this, it might have their lives easier, if they can point to a text in documentation or to a meta.SO answer saying that it is not possible. If they can do this, it would be useful to know about it. (I do not want to discuss here whether the question quota is a good thing and whether there are cases when moderators would have good reasons to remove it. I am simply trying to verify this.)

Can a moderator remove the montly question quota for a particular user?

I did not find an answer to this in other questions. (Maybe I did not look carefully enough.)

Comment: I don't think they can, nor can I imagine there ever being a good reason to.

Comment: No exceptions (other than that the limit is only active on certain sites) are listed on [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)

Comment: Moderators can't do this, but the developers can. Tell users whining at you to email `team 'at' stackexchange.com` (or use the contact link at the bottom of each page) to plead their case.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of Rate-Limit Guide - OP knows the limit and the guide does not tell if / who can disable or work around these limits.

Comment: @Mołot If there was an exception or workaround, it should be listed in the answer to that question. And the asker here is asking for a *resource* or *documentation*. that he can point people to when they ask about this. That question serves that purpose.

Comment: @CodyGray developers can workaround limits and it is not mentioned there, right? And there is no mention moderators cannot. Some people just want to be sure and it's hard for me to blame them.

Comment: Don't think it's a dupe, voting to reopen.

Comment: I agree with @ShaWiz - this is asking specifically if a mod can lift the restriction by request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, moderators can't do anything about this limit. There is no way to exclude a single user from this limit, we can only ask to enable or disable the limit for our entire site.

The limit is not enabled by default on SE 2.0 sites, and it is generally only enabled if the moderators and the community ask for it.

Comment: @hims056 well it's not mentioned under "Deleting" and obviously mods can delete without any limits so still not 100% sure mods are indeed bound to the questions limit.

Comment: @hims056 that's useful information though, would like to know the truth about it. Wonder if Mr. Scientist here knows? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The question limit is not enabled on my sites. I don't think any mod has ever tested this, we would probably need an SE dev to answer this question.

Comment: Or a very active mod on Stack Overflow. :)